# Dart Http Client returns truncated response, truncation varies slightly when I print to console

Tags: json, http, dart, flutter

I am trying to read a JSON Response and build UI with Flutter's FutureBuilder but I am unable to get the entire JSON response on the client. When I try to print the response in two different print statements, the contents among them vary by a tiny bit. Notice how the console print output below differs for **My Posts API Response** and **My Posts Json Response String**.

Could someone explain this behaviour and how to implement a proper listen till the complete JSON Array is received at the client's end?

**Expected API Response -**

```
[{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebc","postId":1,"postUserId":1,"postDescription":"First Post with 2 Photos","postLongDescription":"First Post with 2 Photos","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T10:50:42.389Z","postLocationId":1,"postHasMedia":true,"postActive":true,"postLikesCount":3,"postCommentsCount":1},{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebd","postId":2,"postUserId":2,"postDescription":"Second Post with 1 Video","postLongDescription":"Second Post with 1 Video","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T11:02:00.389Z","postLocationId":2,"postHasMedia":true,"postActive":true,"postLikesCount":12,"postCommentsCount":2},{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebe","postId":3,"postUserId":2,"postDescription":"Third Post with No Video","postLongDescription":"Third Post with No Video","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T11:12:34.389Z","postLocationId":3,"postHasMedia":false,"postActive":true,"postLikesCount":9,"postCommentsCount":0},{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebf","postId":4,"postUserId":3,"postDescription":"Fourth Post with 1 Photo but Disabled","postLongDescription":"Fourth Post with 1 Photo but Disabled","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T11:12:34.389Z","postLocationId":2,"postHasMedia":true,"postActive":false,"postLikesCount":4,"postCommentsCount":0}]
```

**Flutter Bloc Code -**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:MyApp/models/post_model.dart';    
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;    

enum storyTypes {
    timeline,
    myposts
}

class PostsBloc {

Future<PostModel> getPosts(storyTypes storyType) async {
    if (storyType == storyTypes.myposts) {
        final String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/posts/all";
        return await http.get(url).then((getMyPostsApiResponse) {
            if (getMyPostsApiResponse.statusCode != 200) {
            throw Exception("Error with http over network");
            }
            else {
            if (getMyPostsApiResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                print('My Posts API Response - ' + getMyPostsApiResponse.body);                    
                print('My Posts Json Response String - ' + json.decode(getMyPostsApiResponse.body).toString());
                return PostModel.fromJson(json.decode(getMyPostsApiResponse.body));
            }
            else {
                throw Exception('Failed to load post');
            }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Flutter Console Output -**

```
I/flutter (32316): My Posts API Response - [{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebc","postId":1,"postUserId":1,"postDescription":"First Post with 2 Photos","postLongDescription":"First Post with 2 Photos","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T10:50:42.389Z","postLocationId":1,"postHasMedia":true,"postActive":true,"postLikesCount":3,"postCommentsCount":1},{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebd","postId":2,"postUserId":2,"postDescription":"Second Post with 1 Video","postLongDescription":"Second Post with 1 Video","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T11:02:00.389Z","postLocationId":2,"postHasMedia":true,"postActive":true,"postLikesCount":12,"postCommentsCount":2},{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebe","postId":3,"postUserId":2,"postDescription":"Third Post with No Video","postLongDescription":"Third Post with No Video","postDateTime":"2018-07-27T11:12:34.389Z","postLocationId":3,"postHasMedia":false,"postActive":true,"postLikesCount":9,"postCommentsCount":0},{"_id":"5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebf","postId":4,"postUserId":3,"postDescription":"Fourth Post with 1 Photo but Dis    
I/flutter (32316): My Posts Json Response String - [{_id: 5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebc, postId: 1, postUserId: 1, postDescription: First Post with 2 Photos, postLongDescription: First Post with 2 Photos, postDateTime: 2018-07-27T10:50:42.389Z, postLocationId: 1, postHasMedia: true, postActive: true, postLikesCount: 3, postCommentsCount: 1}, {_id: 5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebd, postId: 2, postUserId: 2, postDescription: Second Post with 1 Video, postLongDescription: Second Post with 1 Video, postDateTime: 2018-07-27T11:02:00.389Z, postLocationId: 2, postHasMedia: true, postActive: true, postLikesCount: 12, postCommentsCount: 2}, {_id: 5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebe, postId: 3, postUserId: 2, postDescription: Third Post with No Video, postLongDescription: Third Post with No Video, postDateTime: 2018-07-27T11:12:34.389Z, postLocationId: 3, postHasMedia: false, postActive: true, postLikesCount: 9, postCommentsCount: 0}, {_id: 5bd11c9b8a9fc0a744d1bebf, postId: 4, postUserId: 3, postDescription: Fourth Post with 1 Photo but Disabled, postLongDescr
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're on Android trying to print a long string. To quote from the [documentation about debugging](https://flutter.io/docs/testing/debugging#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs):

> The Dart print() function outputs to the system console, which you can
>   view using flutter logs (which is basically a wrapper around adb
>   logcat).
>
> If you output too much at once, then Android sometimes discards some
>   log lines. To avoid this, you can use debugPrint(), from Flutter’s
>   foundation library. This is a wrapper around print which throttles the
>   output to a level that avoids being dropped by Android’s kernel.

So you could try using `debugPrint` instead.

Import Flutter Package to use debugPrint - `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';`

Comment: Thanks @ringil, I learnt something on debugPrint and general debugging in Flutter from the documentation but the truncation is _invariably existent_ when I print using `debugPrint` and `debugPrintSynchronously` methods but thanks! :)

Comment: Note that if the `jsonDecode` succeeds it is _very_ unlikely to be truncated before that point or you'd end up with a decode error. The truncation is still likely happening somewhere in the printing.

Answer (score 3):

That's just the console truncating after so many characters.

Notice that you are printing two different things:

`getMyPostsApiResponse.body` is the json received from the server.

`json.decode(getMyPostsApiResponse.body).toString()` is the decoded `List`'s toString (which excludes the quote marks, which is why the lengths of the strings are different)

Comment: You have a point on the missing quotes and so the length of the response varying slight a bit due to JSON decoding but it doesn't explain the truncation of the response. Thanks anyway :)