# Why http.post() response body is not fully printed? Does it related to NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, mvvm, flutter-http

I'm using IGDB API to list the games. I'm getting this console output from `print(queryResponse.body);` which has missing data compared to Postman's response body.

Console:

```
I/flutter (16534): [
I/flutter (16534):   {
I/flutter (16534):     "id": 33260,
I/flutter (16534):     "category": 0,
I/flutter (16534):     "cover": 129073,
I/flutter (16534):     "created_at": 1495739021,
I/flutter (16534):     "external_games": [
I/flutter (16534):       5526,
I/flutter (16534):       107828,
I/flutter (16534):       1927694
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "first_release_date": 1459987200,
I/flutter (16534):     "game_modes": [
I/flutter (16534):       1
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "genres": [
I/flutter (16534):       15,
I/flutter (16534):       32
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "name": "The Fifth Expedition",
I/flutter (16534):     "platforms": [
I/flutter (16534):       3,
I/flutter (16534):       6
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "release_dates": [
I/flutter (16534):       77732,
I/flutter (16534):       77733
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "screenshots": [
I/flutter (16534):       58357,
I/flutter (16534):       58358,
I/flutter (16534):       58359,
I/flutter (16534):       58360,
I/flutter (16534):       58361
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "similar_games": [
I/flutter (16534):       25311,
I/flutter (16534):       25640,
I/flutter (16534):       34024,
I/flutter (16534):       36553,
I/flutter (16534):       37419,
I/flutter (16534):       65827,
I/flutter (16534):       111043,
I/flutter (16534):       111130,
I/flutter (16534):       113895,
I/flutter (16534):       118091
I/flutter (16534):     ],
I/flutter (16534):     "slug": "the-fifth-expedition",
I/flutter (16534):     "status": 4,
I/flutter (16534):     "summary": "Guide your team of explorers into the treacherous depths of an ancient machine. \n \nOn a mission to restore the old mechanisms to life and to save your people on the surface, who rely on the age old construct for food and shelter.",
I/flutter (16534):     "tags": [
I/flutter (16534):       1,
I/flutter (16534):       268435471,
I/flutter (16534):       268435
```

Postman:
[image]

And here is my code for api calls:

```
class WebService {
  Future<List<Game>> fetchService() async {
    final auth = await http.post(Secrets.authUrl);
    final responseBody = jsonDecode(auth.body);

    final queryResponse = await http.post(ApplicationConstants.IGDBGamesUrl,
        headers: {
          "Client-ID": "${Secrets.IGDBAuth["client_id"]}",
          "Authorization": "Bearer ${responseBody["access_token"]}",
        },
        body: "fields *; limit 5;");

    print(queryResponse.body);
    if (auth.statusCode == 200) {
      return gameFromJson(queryResponse.body);
    }
    return [];
  }
}
```

I couldn't figure out why postman output is different than printed output. Because I'm getting this error when `gameFromJson(queryResponse.body)` is called:

```
E/flutter (16534): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (16534): Receiver: null
E/flutter (16534): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic)
```

And this is my model for the game. This is what quicktype.io returns when I put the Postman output:

```
List<Game> gameFromJson(String str) {
  return List<Game>.from(json.decode(str).map((final x) => Game.fromJson(x)));
}

String gameToJson(List<Game> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Game {
  Game({
    required this.id,
    required this.ageRatings,
    required this.aggregatedRating,
    required this.aggregatedRatingCount,
    required this.alternativeNames,
    required this.artworks,
    required this.category,
    required this.cover,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.externalGames,
    required this.firstReleaseDate,
    required this.follows,
    required this.gameEngines,
    required this.gameModes,
    required this.genres,
    required this.involvedCompanies,
    required this.keywords,
    required this.name,
    required this.platforms,
    required this.playerPerspectives,
    required this.rating,
    required this.ratingCount,
    required this.releaseDates,
    required this.screenshots,
    required this.similarGames,
    required this.slug,
    required this.storyline,
    required this.summary,
    required this.tags,
    required this.themes,
    required this.totalRating,
    required this.totalRatingCount,
    required this.updatedAt,
    required this.url,
    required this.versionParent,
    required this.versionTitle,
    required this.videos,
    required this.websites,
    required this.checksum,
  });

  int id;
  List<int> ageRatings;
  int aggregatedRating;
  int aggregatedRatingCount;
  List<int> alternativeNames;
  List<int> artworks;
  int category;
  int cover;
  int createdAt;
  List<int> externalGames;
  int firstReleaseDate;
  int follows;
  List<int> gameEngines;
  List<int> gameModes;
  List<int> genres;
  List<int> involvedCompanies;
  List<int> keywords;
  String name;
  List<int> platforms;
  List<int> playerPerspectives;
  double rating;
  int ratingCount;
  List<int> releaseDates;
  List<int> screenshots;
  List<int> similarGames;
  String slug;
  String storyline;
  String summary;
  List<int> tags;
  List<int> themes;
  double totalRating;
  int totalRatingCount;
  int updatedAt;
  String url;
  int versionParent;
  String versionTitle;
  List<int> videos;
  List<int> websites;
  String checksum;

  factory Game.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      Game(
        id: json["id"],
        ageRatings: List<int>.from(json["age_ratings"].map((x) => x)),
        aggregatedRating: json["aggregated_rating"],
        aggregatedRatingCount: json["aggregated_rating_count"],
        alternativeNames: List<int>.from(
            json["alternative_names"].map((x) => x)),
        artworks: List<int>.from(json["artworks"].map((x) => x)),
        category: json["category"],
        cover: json["cover"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"],
        externalGames: List<int>.from(json["external_games"].map((x) => x)),
        firstReleaseDate: json["first_release_date"],
        follows: json["follows"],
        gameEngines: List<int>.from(json["game_engines"].map((x) => x)),
        gameModes: List<int>.from(json["game_modes"].map((x) => x)),
        genres: List<int>.from(json["genres"].map((x) => x)),
        involvedCompanies: List<int>.from(
            json["involved_companies"].map((x) => x)),
        keywords: List<int>.from(json["keywords"].map((x) => x)),
        name: json["name"],
        platforms: List<int>.from(json["platforms"].map((x) => x)),
        playerPerspectives: List<int>.from(
            json["player_perspectives"].map((x) => x)),
        rating: json["rating"].toDouble(),
        ratingCount: json["rating_count"],
        releaseDates: List<int>.from(json["release_dates"].map((x) => x)),
        screenshots: List<int>.from(json["screenshots"].map((x) => x)),
        similarGames: List<int>.from(json["similar_games"].map((x) => x)),
        slug: json["slug"],
        storyline: json["storyline"],
        summary: json["summary"],
        tags: List<int>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
        themes: List<int>.from(json["themes"].map((x) => x)),
        totalRating: json["total_rating"].toDouble(),
        totalRatingCount: json["total_rating_count"],
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
        url: json["url"],
        versionParent: json["version_parent"],
        versionTitle: json["version_title"],
        videos: List<int>.from(json["videos"].map((x) => x)),
        websites: List<int>.from(json["websites"].map((x) => x)),
        checksum: json["checksum"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {
        "id": id,
        "age_ratings": List<dynamic>.from(ageRatings.map((x) => x)),
        "aggregated_rating": aggregatedRating,
        "aggregated_rating_count": aggregatedRatingCount,
        "alternative_names": List<dynamic>.from(alternativeNames.map((x) => x)),
        "artworks": List<dynamic>.from(artworks.map((x) => x)),
        "category": category,
        "cover": cover,
        "created_at": createdAt,
        "external_games": List<dynamic>.from(externalGames.map((x) => x)),
        "first_release_date": firstReleaseDate,
        "follows": follows,
        "game_engines": List<dynamic>.from(gameEngines.map((x) => x)),
        "game_modes": List<dynamic>.from(gameModes.map((x) => x)),
        "genres": List<dynamic>.from(genres.map((x) => x)),
        "involved_companies": List<dynamic>.from(
            involvedCompanies.map((x) => x)),
        "keywords": List<dynamic>.from(keywords.map((x) => x)),
        "name": name,
        "platforms": List<dynamic>.from(platforms.map((x) => x)),
        "player_perspectives": List<dynamic>.from(
            playerPerspectives.map((x) => x)),
        "rating": rating,
        "rating_count": ratingCount,
        "release_dates": List<dynamic>.from(releaseDates.map((x) => x)),
        "screenshots": List<dynamic>.from(screenshots.map((x) => x)),
        "similar_games": List<dynamic>.from(similarGames.map((x) => x)),
        "slug": slug,
        "storyline": storyline,
        "summary": summary,
        "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
        "themes": List<dynamic>.from(themes.map((x) => x)),
        "total_rating": totalRating,
        "total_rating_count": totalRatingCount,
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
        "url": url,
        "version_parent": versionParent,
        "version_title": versionTitle,
        "videos": List<dynamic>.from(videos.map((x) => x)),
        "websites": List<dynamic>.from(websites.map((x) => x)),
        "checksum": checksum,
      };
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [Dart Http Client returns truncated response, truncation varies slightly when I print to console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53267877/)?

Comment: @jamesdlin - Thanks, that helped me to print the response fully. But, if the response body is not broken why does it say that the 'map' was called on null? The status code is 200 and all keys are included in the Game object

Comment: The server successfully returned a response to you.  Your null error occurs *in your client* (presumably when trying to deserialize the JSON result; in all the places that you do `json["..."].map(...)`, you don't check if `json["..."]` is valid first).

Comment: As you said, each object had a different amount of keys. When I pick the common key(like id) for each object it worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `debugPrint()` instead of the `print()`